# Statistics of iOS versions that the users are running the app on

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app on Apple Store and I would want to know the breakdown of devices running iOS 7, iOS 7.1, iOS 8, etc. However, this information doesn't seem to exist on iTunes Connect which is just showing breakdown of devices like iPhone, iPad.

My question is can we find the breakdown of the devices based on iOS version for an app on Apple Store? This will help me decide which iOS versions the new release should be targeted.

Thanks.

Comment: Use brand new App Analytics beta from iTunes Connect for everything but iOS version.

Answer (score 62):

Now you can check application usage by iOS version at
https://analytics.itunes.apple.com.
The URL is memorizable enough. Mnemonics!

Let me attach a screenshot from a different post as an example:

[iTunesConnect - Download automatically app's usage analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620111/itunesconnect-download-automatically-apps-usage-analytics)
[image: sample]

For more screenshots, please check this post:

[Missing iOS 7 App Usage data in iTunes App Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881793/missing-ios-7-app-usage-data-in-itunes-app-analytics)

Answer (score 45):

The answer by computingfreak is a little outdated now as iTunes Connect was changed to AppStore Connect in the past couple of years. As of January 2021, one can open AppStoreConnect, go to the Analytics section, choose your app, change the measurement drop down Platform Version and view a breakup in different iOS versions, like illustrated in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can go to Appstore connect-> Analytics-> Metrics, Here you can select Usage -> Active devices and filter by IOS version to see how many users are using which  version.

Answer (score 0):

If app is already on the store then i doubt tracking this would not be possible.

what you are looking for is the analytics so try using open source tool named [flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) OR [google analytics](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios) to track this.

But you may integrate this in the new version of your mobile app

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a very simple web service for getting the Statistics of iOS versions

You will get the current version from the below Objective C code

```
UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *deviceSystemVersion = dev.systemVersion;
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to install something like [Flurry Analytics](https://developer.yahoo.com/analytics/) to get that. iTunes Connect does not provide that level of detail.

Comment: Seems like a very, very basic piece of information to provide. It feels like Apple probably wants devs to forget that old iOS versions exist.