# Missing iOS 7 App Usage data in iTunes App Analytics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store-connect, analytics

I have an app that is used by users running iOS versions from 6 to 9.
But i can see app metrics only for (operating system) platform versions 8 and 9.
There is no data about iOS 7 or earlier.

I checked the [iTunes Connect App Analytics Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/iTunes_Connect_App_Analytics_Guide_v1.pdf?utm_content=buffer90b4e&utm_medium=social&utm_source=plus.google.com&utm_campaign=buffer) (pdf) & [App Analytics Guide](http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/en.lproj/static.html) (html).

It says "devices using iOS 7 or earlier are not included in App Analytics, but they are included in Sales and Trends".

"App Analytics only displays data from devices using iOS 8 or later".

I would like to know why it is so?
What can i do to find out usage counts of users with previous versions of iOS?

images:

1. Line Graph [image: line]
2. Bar Graph [image: bar]
3. Area Graph [image: area]

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Analytics or something similar can be used, with OS version as a custom parameter to track.

i think this might help.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/customdimsmets#overview